# A simple test connection with the "nc" tool using Robotframework?

Tags: frameworks, robotframework, netcat

I'm trying to execute a simple Test Connection test in Robotframework, between two IP addresses in the same network. What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. On one side
   Execute Command echo Hello | nc -l 51111
2. to catch the "Hello" message on the other:
   Execute Command    'nc ip 51111'

, using the standard netcat tool.

For this, I run the Test Script.robot:

```
Library                Process
Library                SSHLibrary
Suite Setup            Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown         Close All Connections

*** Variables ***
${HOST}                ip.my.dev.vm
${USERNAME}            user 
${PASSWORD}            password
${HOST_PDG}            ip.server1
${HOST_IDPF}           ip.server2

*** Test Cases ***
Step 1 Connect Server1 and send Hello to space 
  Open Connection And Log In Server1
  ${output}=          Execute Command    'echo Hello | nc -l 51111'
  Should Not Be Equal    ${output}         Hello

Step 2 Connect to Server2 and retrieve Hello 
  Open Connection And Log In Server2
  ${output}=         Execute Command    'nc ip.server2 51111'
  Should Be Equal    ${output}       Hello  

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
 Open Connection     ${HOST}
 Login               ${USERNAME}        ${PASSWORD}  
Open Connection And Log In Server1
Open Connection     ${HOST_PDG}
 Login               ${USERNAME}        ${PASSWORD}
Open Connection And Log In Server2
 Open Connection     ${HOST_IDPF}
 Login               ${USERNAME}        ${PASSWORD}
```

This script stops after the first passed test step, and from the Server2 I never able to catch this Hello message.

The same test over command line with the nc tool works perfectly.

1. ssh Server1
2. echo Hello | nc -l 51111
3. ssh Server2
4. nc ip.server2 51111
   (see the Hello message)

What is the problem to do it over the ROBOT Framework?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because the robotframework execution is serial, while your aim implies parallelism - after running the `netcat` server on Server1, *in parallel* you want to connect to it from Server2.

This is what you're doing when you did it manually, but this is not what happened in the RF cases: in the framework, you've ran test 1, it did its steps, and finished (with some pass/fail status, but that's not important now). When it was done, the service was not running; so when in test 2 you tried to connect to it - it rightfully failed.

Here's what you can do - make the two steps (bringing up the service, and connecting to it) be executed in parallel. The easiest way is for that to be in the same case; and for the service to be running in the background you have to use not the `Execute Command` - which waits for its target to finish, but [Start Command](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Start%20Command) which starts it in the background immediately returns.
Its usage is a little bit different, in terms of getting the output and communicating with it, you can read how in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

...and I found that...

Without changing the original script much, if the quotes around the both command are deleted, and `Start Command` is used instead of `Execute Command`, at the listener side (as Todor suggested, thank you!), the script will works as it is, giving the right results.

Comment: It works for you not because of the removal of the quotes, but because you switched to `Start Command` (this makes it continue running in the background). By the way, be sure you stop the service at the end of the case (thus I said it's easier to do it in a case)/or the suite - otherwise you may end up with the netcat still running on Server 1 long after you've finished your cases run.